# Ng model not taking default ng value in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

i have input with default value 0 , but this value not getting 
my js getting error undefined ,if i enter any value it is showing .
but i want to show default value

```
<tr ng-repeat="r in rvm" >
                <td>
                    <input type="text" lass="input-large" ng-value="2.00" ng-model="rvm.val1" name="val1" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="addRow1()">Add</button>
                </td>
                        </tr>
```

JS

```
var ReceiptsApp = angular.module('ReceiptsApp', []);

ReceiptsApp.controller('ReceiptsController', function ($scope) {
 $scope.rvm = [{}];
   $scope.addRow1 = function ( ) {
        alert($scope.rvm.val1);
    }
       });
```

js bin link here

[enter link description here](http://jsbin.com/mimonetiri/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: link not working.... add link in stackoverflow by pressing `ctrl+L` key .. then paste the link over there and change title on highlighted part

Comment: hii i have put the answer, check it

Answer (score 0):

Just set a default value in the controller:

```
ReceiptsApp.controller('ReceiptsController', function ($scope) {

  $scope.rvm.val1 = 'your default value';
});
```

If you read [this link about ngValue](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue) you will see that it's not supposed to be used with a normal input (when you've also set `ng-model` on it), but rather for `radio` inputs and `option` elements. Your best solution is setting the value in the controller, as you should do.

> It can also be used to achieve one-way binding of a given expression to an input element such as an input[text] or a textarea, when that element ***does not*** use ngModel.

Comment: i want to take ng-value as default

Answer (score 0):

You can either set it inside your controller

```
ReceiptsApp.controller('ReceiptsController', function ($scope) {

  $scope.rvm.val1 = '0.00';
});
```

or using `ng-init`

```
<input type="text" lass="input-large" ng-init="rvm.val1='0.00'" ng-model="rvm.val1" name="val1" />
```

Comment: Ng-init is considered bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" lass="input-large" ng-value="2.00" ng-model="rvm.val1" name="val1" />
```

Problem is you are using `rvm.val1` where `rvm` is `array` not an `object` in `array`

Change `ng-model="rvm.val1"` to `ng-model="r.val1"`

then you will be able to keep track of each value individually.

Inorder to initialize a value

```
<tr ng-repeat="r in rvm" ng-init="r.val1= 2.00">
```

Then in

```
 $scope.addRow1 = function (index) {
       // access individual object in rvm..
       alert($scope.rvm[index].val1);
       // push a new object
       $scope.rvm.push({});
   }
```

[JSBin](https://jsbin.com/vomosupodi/1/edit?html,js,output)

If you don't want to use `ng-init`

You can do this

Each time you push a new item initialize the `val1`

```
$scope.rvm.push({val1:  2.00});
```

[JsBin](https://jsbin.com/gihimupore/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

```
var ReceiptsApp = angular.module('ReceiptsApp', []);

ReceiptsApp.controller('ReceiptsController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.rvm = [{}];
    $scope.rvm.val1=0;
    $scope.addRow1 = function ( ) {
        if($scope.rvm.val1 == ''){
            $scope.rvm.val1=0;
            alert($scope.rvm.val1);
        } else {
            alert($scope.rvm.val1);
        }
    }
});
```

Hi i have took a if condition where i am checking if input field is blank then it will initialise  `$scope.rvm.val1=0;` and showing in alert.
it will work

Comment: if it is helpful for you then let me know.